# set ip based restriction on hosted openstreetmap nominatim service

Tags: php, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have installed openstreetmap nominatim planet file in my server.

To install this I have followed their guidelines from this page http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation .

I want to limited nominatim api access by blocking all ip except one ip.

How can I do this? I have check nominatim settings.php file but it only allow to block in case of abuse.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration for your webserver or firewall, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, I can do this using nginx! But I would like to know if I can do the same from nominatim. @scai